# How to integrate prebid.js configuration and sent request to prebid bidders?

Tags: prebid.js, header-bidding

I have downloaded prebid js script file from prebid website and made request using that file. while deliver the ad It shows following error.

**prebid shows error message :Trying to make a request for bidder that does not exist: rubicon**

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you selected `Rubicon` as a bid adapter when you download prebid.js.
Alternatively if you are building from source, make sure you pass in the paramater.
ie:

`gulp build --modules=rubiconBidAdapter`